Visual Studio automatically removes new files from custom MSBuild Task
Is there something I am doing wrong with this custom MSBuild target to cause Visual Studio to do this behavior?
I have a custom MSBuild task that bundles separate javascript files into a single file, it's used like this in the csproj file:
<ItemGroup>
    <ScriptBundler Include="**\*.js" Exclude="app.js" />
</ItemGroup>

Problem: When I add a new myNewFile.js that matches the path in the Include, Visual Studio automatically adds this line into the csproj:
<ScriptBundler Remove="myNewFile.js" />

It usually takes me or another co-worker about an hour of debugging to figure out why my new script isn't being bundled correctly.
Question: Is there something different I can do with Include="**\*.js" to stop this from happening? Alternatively is there something I can do in the custom task to tell Visual Studio to be greedy with new files added?
The custom build task accepts input for files like this:
[Required]
public ITaskItem[] Files { get; set; }

Edit: And it is added into the project like this:
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <BundleScripts Files="@(ScriptBundle)" 
                 ProjectDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" />
</Target>


Is ScriptBundler your custom task? The MSBuild code that you show is creating an Item collection named ScriptBundler and is not invoking a task. Do you have a target that contains <ScriptBundler Files="@(ScriptBundler)"/>, i.e. you invoke the ScriptBundler task with the ScriptBundler Item collection?

@JonathanDodds I added details on how it's used in the Target, it's exactly like you think. (sorry I forgot about this part)

This may be a typo in the question but the name of the Item ScriptBundler and the name of the Item reference @(scriptBundle) must match.

@JonathanDodds yes, just a question typo

MSBuild has two phases: evaluation and execution. "Top level" ItemGroups will be evaluated in the evaluation phase. The ScriptBundler ItemGroup can be moved from the "top level" to inside the target which will move the evaluation from the evaluation phase to the execution phase and when the target is actually executed. This should make no difference to the results of the wildcard but effectively removes the ScriptBundler Item from "design time".

@JonathanDodds this would work but the Target is actually in another DLL, it is automatically imported via a nuget package. I need to be able to exclude things from the ScriptBundler ItemGroup via adding <ScriptBundle Include=".." Exclude=".."/>. But maybe I can still exclude by manually adding <ScriptBundle Remove=".."/> in the design time project?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.


Is there something I am doing wrong with this custom MSBuild target to cause Visual Studio to do this behavior?

No, based on my test, i can reproduce the same behavior in my VS2022(17.10.4).
When i add a new file to a MSBuild item, the <Remove> element is automatically added to the project file. I guess this behavior is by design and serves a specific purpose:Incremental Builds.
If you want to prevent the automatic addition of  elements, here is a workaround: using Condition="'$(DesignTimeBuild)' != 'true'" in the ItemGroup.
For example:
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(DesignTimeBuild)' != 'true'">
    <ScriptBundler Include="wwwroot\js\*.js" Exclude="wwwroot\js\app.js" />
</ItemGroup>

For more information about DesignTimeBuild, please refer to doc:
https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/blob/main/docs/design-time-builds.md
